# How to run a hook on a Xmonad Window via keybinding

Tags: haskell, window-managers, xmonad, xmonad-contrib

I am looking for a way to replicate the behaviour of `doCenterFloat` in my managehook to a keybinding.
I would like to keep the windows 'natural' size. For example, when i create an OpenGL window with size 800x600, I would manually have to add the title of the window to my XMonad config, otherwise it would be tiled and the contents of the window would be stretched.

Here is the code i am trying to replicate to a key binding

```
myManageHook = composeAll
     [ title =? "OpenGL"              --> doCenterFloat ]
```

The above code makes the window display correctly. I have tried functions that toggle a normal float (not centerFloat) but they display at the tiled sized, like this
[Xmonad: Float and resize windows to its “natural size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15273/xmonad-float-and-resize-windows-to-its-natural-size)

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: It's not clear what your question is asking. I assume it's just how to run the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
runQuery :: Query a -> Window -> X a
```

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.16/docs/XMonad-Config-Prime.html#v:runQuery

```
withFocused :: (Window -> X ()) -> X ()
```

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.16/docs/XMonad-Config-Prime.html#v:withFocused

Using the above two functions, where `myQuery` would be set your your `Query` (like `doCenterFloat`).

```
myQuery = undefined :: Query
withFocused (\window -> runQuery myQuery window)
```